# Flexibility of truck's steering wheel with keyboard

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

As I don't have a steering wheel to play Euro Truck, I only use the keyboard. Everytime I change direction, pressing left or right arrow keys, the steering wheel does a fast change of angle, instead of changing it slowly.

Can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in settings -> controls section there is "steering sensivity" option - sliding it changes the speed at which in-game wheel is turned - for a gaming steering wheel you set it to maximum(right-most), but for keyboard or gamepad it is useful to lower it.[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is a way to change the keyboard to be less sensitive but you can steer with your mouse which I did find much easier. You can fine tune the mouse turning. 
Info [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/trucksim/wiki/controllers)